# Custom sort of DataTable where index is needed

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

As the title says I need a custom sort for my DataTable where I make use of the index of a DataRow and the result should be EnumerableRowCollection or OrderedEnumerableRowCollection because I want a table (default order) and a DataView (custom order).

The order I want: first sort by several columns (e.g. name, surname, ...). Then split the table in table1 and table2 (just half of the table). Then alternately choose from the first and the second table. The result should be

row of table1
row of table2
row of table1

the original table should not be affected and the result should be a reference to the original table.

```cs
internal static DataView GetSortedView(this DataTable table)
{
    return table.GetSortedTable().AsDataView();
}

internal static void OrderedEnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> GetSortedTable(this DataTable table)
{

int half = table.Rows.Count / 2;
//sort columns by name for example
var enumerable = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(field => field.Field<string>("Name"), new NaturalStringComparer());

//here is the tricky part
enumerable= enumerable.OrderBy(row =>
                    {
                        int myIndex = ?; //I cannot use table.Rows.IndexOf(row) because the order of the current OrderedEnumerableRowCollection should be used and not the default order of the table

                        bool upperHalf = myIndex > half;
                        if (upperHalf)
                        {
                            myIndex -= half;
                        }

                        return new CustomSortItem(myIndex , upperHalf);
                    }, new CustomSort());
return enumerable;
}
```

I have tried to add a new column for indices first, but this isn't really working because when I try to remove the column, in the end, I receive an exception because of lazy loading.

```cs
internal static void OrderedEnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> GetSortedTable(this DataTable table)
{

//create another column for an index
string tempSortName = "[TEMP_SORT]";
table.Columns.Add(tempSortName);

//sort columns by Name for example
var enumerable= table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(field => field.Field<string>("Name"), new NaturalStringComparer());

//set the temporary order (index)
int count = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in enumerable)
{
    row[tempSortName] = count++;
}

//here is the tricky part
int half = table.Rows.Count / 2;
enumerable= enumerable.OrderBy(row =>
                    {
                        int myIndex = int.parse(row[tempSortName].ToString()); //exception here. column not found

                        bool upperHalf = myIndex  > half;
                        if (upperHalf)
                        {
                            myIndex  -= half;
                        }

                        return new CustomSortItem(myIndex , upperHalf);
                    }, new CustomSort());

                    table.Columns.Remove(tempSortName);
return enumerable;
}
```

I also don't want to use IEnumerable, because when I create a DataView I have to create another table in order to create one and then the reference is lost (view.Table isn't the original table just a copy without references).

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> enumerable...
enumerable.CopyToDataTable().AsDataView();
// I have to call CopyToDataTable() in order to create a DataView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found a solution and the solution is different for `GetSortedTable` and `GetSortedView` (each has it's own solution). I would appreciate it if somebody has a better solution.

```cs
internal static void DataView GetSortedView(this DataTable table)
{

   //create another column for an index
   string tempSortName = "[TEMP_SORT]";
   table.Columns.Add(tempSortName);

   //sort columns by Name for example
   var enumerable= table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(field => field.Field<string>("Name"), new NaturalStringComparer());

   //set the temporary order (index)
   int count = 0;
   foreach(DataRow row in enumerable)
   {
       row[tempSortName] = count++;
   }

   //here is the tricky part
   int half = table.Rows.Count / 2;
   enumerable= enumerable.OrderBy(row =>
    {

      if (int.TryParse(row[tempSortName]?.ToString(), out int myIndex )) //everything here is triggered if row[tempSortName] is set... or before it is set... idk... wtf. so there is a new column but there are not any indices in it (or just one)
       {
         myIndex++;
         bool upperHalf = myIndex  > half;
         if (upperHalf)
         {
            myIndex  -= half;
         }
         return new CustomSortItem(myIndex , upperHalf);
       }
    }, new CustomSort());

   DataView view = enumerable.AsDataView();
   view.Table.Columns.Remove(tempSortName);

   return view;
}


internal static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetSortedTable(this DataTable table)
{
   IEnumerable<DataRow> result;
   //sort columns by Name for example
   var enumerable= table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(field => field.Field<string>("Name"), new NaturalStringComparer());
   int half =  table.Rows.Count / 2;
   IEnumerable<DataRow> one = enumerable.Take(half);
   IEnumerable<DataRow> two = enumerable.Skip(half);
   result = one.InterleaveEnumerationsOfEqualLength(two);
   return result;
 }

internal static IEnumerable<DataRow> InterleaveEnumerationsOfEqualLength<DataRow>(this IEnumerable<DataRow> first, IEnumerable<DataRow> second)
{
   using (IEnumerator<DataRow> enumerator1 = first.GetEnumerator(), enumerator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
   {
      while (enumerator1.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext())
      {
         yield return enumerator1.Current;
         yield return enumerator2.Current;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the two parameter version of `Select` to count the rows in order?

```
enumerable = enumerable.Select((r, i) => new { r, i })
                       .OrderBy(ri => {
                            var upperHalf = ri.i > half;
                            var myIndex = ri.i - (upperHalf ? half : 0);
                            return new CustomSortItem(myIndex, upperHalf);
                        }, new CustomSort());
```

Comment: The `Select` statement returns `IEnumerable<DataRow>` instead of `EnumerableDataRowCollection<DataRow>`. With `IEnumerable` I cannot create a view with a reference to the original table, but `EnumerableDataRowcollection` can do it.